# Зачем нужна метка [паттерн]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Вопросы с меткой [паттерн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd) обычно идут бок о бок с 1-й из 3-х меток (1 вопрос был по MVVM):

- [шаблоны-проектирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)
- [solid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solid)
- [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Если 1-й из вышеуказанных меток не наблюдается, то в самом вопросе явно говорится, к какой категории вопросов он относится ([пример №1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1319490/%d0%a4%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c), [пример №2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1318363/unity-2d-3d-c-solid), [пример №3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253894/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)).

Возникает логичный вопрос: зачем эта метка тогда нужна?

Comment: По идее, надо её синонимизировать с [шаблонами-проектирования]

Comment: @Kromster по идее да, но слово "паттерн" даже к solid приплетают, хотя solid это о принципах. и что делать с [таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246343/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5), например, вопросом? там 2 метки: regex и gof, синонимом тут не поможешь

Comment: Кажется вы не ту ссылку приложили

Comment: @Kromster почему не ту? [паттерн], как вы сказали, о [шаблоны-проектирования], а в вопросе, на который я ссылался, метка [паттерн] обозначает паттерн для [регулярные-выражения].

Comment: Вы пишете, *"там 2 метки: regex и gof"* - я не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду, какой там gof?

Comment: @Kromster если синонимировать [паттерн] к [шаблоны-проектирования], то выйдет, что под вопросом метки [регулярные-выражения] и [шаблоны-проектирования], хотя автор вопроса под словом "паттерн" явно имел в виду не 1 из шаблонов проектирования, а паттерн для регулярного выражения

Comment: В подобных вопросах, метку [паттерн] достаточно просто убрать. Так как она не несет дополнительного смысла. Очевидно, что если ТС нужна регулярка, то в ней будет некоторый паттерн и так.

Comment: @Kromster метка [удаление-метки] под моим вопросом на это недвусмысленно намекает, но я не понимаю, чем эта метка отличается от метки, например, [ошибка]. тоже общая метка, тоже нельзя быть по ней специалистом, тоже связывает абсолютно разные области программирования и т.д.

Comment: Удалить метку с 20 вопросами - дело не хитрое. Но мы предпочитаем синоним, если в большинстве случаев метку можно заменить на другую, более крупную.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight удалить и добавить метку по значению. посмотрите примеры в моих вопросах. если [паттерн] употребляется с другой меткой, более узкой, то удалить только [паттерн]. синоним не помешает, но нужно зачистить вопросы под которыми написано что-то вроде: "[регулярные-выражения] [паттерн]"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Предлагаю синонимизировать (синонимизировано 30.04.2023) к [шаблоны-проектирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), как уже высказывалось в комментариях. Аналогичный подход принят на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/design-patterns/synonyms):

> [image: Синонимы enSO]

Более того, уже [используются синонимы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/synonyms) с множественным числом ("паттерны") и английским словом ("pattern"):

> [image: Синонимы ruSO]

Проголосовать за синоним должно быть можно на [странице ожидающих синонимизации меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) или непосредственно на [странице синонимов метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/synonyms).