# Как работает наполнение таблицы ожидающих подтверждения синонимов?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, синонимы-меток

Есть [страница ожидающих подтверждения синонимов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested). Её наполнение формируется с учётом возможности участника проголосовать (5 баллов по целевой метке). В моём случае таблица выглядит сейчас так:

> [image: Ожидающие подтверждения синонимы]

В данном случае голосовать я не могу, т.к. являюсь автором предложений о синонимизации.
Дополнительно недавно я [предложил ещё один синоним](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11681/176217) к метке [паттерн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd). Однако, в таблице почему-то его нет, хотя видно на [странице синонимов самой метки "паттерн"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/synonyms).

Почему я не вижу этот предложенный синоним на странице ожидающих подтверждения синонимов?